# Checking current git branch with ifneq in Makefile

Tags: git, makefile

I'm trying to get my makefile to check that it's running on the correct branch and throw and error if not.

I'm using `ifneq` to compare them and  `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` to get the checked out branch, but it will not see them as equal. How can I fix this?

Right now the the code looks like this:

```
ifneq ($(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD), master)
    $(error Not on branch master)
else
    git checkout gh-pages
    git merge master
    git checkout master
endif
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no such make function as `$(git ...)`, so that variable reference expands to the empty string.  You're always running:

```
ifneq (, master)
```

which will be always true.

You want to use the `shell` GNU make function:

```
ifneq ($(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD),master)
```